# Network analysis question

Tags: dependencies

I have an 
Activity i has a SF relationship with 3 days of lag with activity j. i starts on Tuesday morning and is 2 days long. j is 4 days long. When will j begin?

How do you calculate the dates?

Comment: This seems like a very rudimentary calculation, is this a homework/quiz question? What calculation have you tried and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Scrum? That doesn't sound like scrum. Are you sure you haven't mis-tagged?

Comment: Calendar days? Business days? You've provided no useful context.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. `j` starts when `i` is **done** and `j` was prioritized to be next. Planning to start `j` on a certain day would require another method, SCRUM does not do this.